# Angular 13 build is very slow with ng build --prod=true

Tags: angular, build, angular13

Recently migrated to Angular 13 and build time is approximately 24mins to 30 mins minimum.
The same project was taking 10 mins to build earlier with Angular 6.
Did do some changes in angular.json file but couldn't see any big difference.

[image: build]

Also attaching Angular.json file below

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Dashboard": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "core-js",
              "raf",
              "xlsx",
              "@babel/runtime"
            ],
            "outputPath": "dist/Dashboard",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/Web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
             
              "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/rhea/theme.css",
              "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css",
              "node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/styles/material.css",
              "node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-base/styles/material.css",
              "node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-buttons/styles/material.css",
              "node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-inputs/styles/material.css",
              "node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-popups/styles/material.css",
              "node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-lists/styles/material.css",
              "node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-splitbuttons/styles/material.css",
              "node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-calendars/styles/material.css",
              "node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars/styles/material.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-layouts/styles/material.css",
              "node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-navigations/styles/material.css",
              "node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-inputs/styles/material.css",
              "node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-notifications/styles/material.css",
              "node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-dropdowns/styles/material.css",
              "node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-buttons/styles/material.css",
              "node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css",
              "node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-dropdowns/styles/material.css",
              "node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids/styles/material.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.js",
              "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.min.js"
            ],
            "aot": false,
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization":
               {"scripts":true,
              "styles":{
                "minify": true,
                "inlineCritical": true
              },
              "fonts":true},
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "uat": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "local": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.local.ts"
                }
              ],
          "optimization": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "outputHashing": "none",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "progress": false
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Dashboard:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Dashboard:build:production"
            },
            "local": {
              "browserTarget": "Dashboard:build:local"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Dashboard:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Dashboard-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "Dashboard:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "Dashboard:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "Dashboard",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "e333499c-dad7-4f87-a7b8-78fd13a99d5b"
  }
}
```

Computer specs are as follows...dont think this could be a problem though

Processor   11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz   2.42 GHz

Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.7 GB usable)

Windows 11

Answer (score 0):

While I don't see anything suspicious in file provided I am thinking what's the time that it takes to do e2e tests? Diagnose that.

You can try running to see if it provides any insights into what is taking so much time.

```
ng build --verbose
```

Or generate a build profile to analyze

```
ng build --prod --profile
```

What is the number of dependencies? Are they optimal? Your chunk files look small though, and PC specs are modern. This leads me to believe this time consumed doesn't just come from the build process itself.